# How to assert values that An Exception class contains

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have a One Exception with a Type value inside it. I am using this exception `ContentNotFoundException` with type attribute that's says what content is missing (name, age, sex, etc.)

So while unittesting, i would like to know the type of the exception. I have been using assertRaises but I am not able to verify if the right type has been thrown as exception.

SO i had an inde where i will have a try catch inside a test function and I can assertEqual the type inside the catch. But this seemed a bit odd. Is there any other way to do it ? Or should i actually create one class per exception ? Like NameNotFoundException, AgeNotFoundException, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Pytest, you can use code like this:

```py
with pytest.raises(YourExceptionType) as ex:
    some_code_that_should_throw();

assert ex.value == "something"
```

Note that the `assert` must be outside the `with` block, as the `with` block is exited by the exception.

See [the Pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions) for details.